# How can I use 2 Dimensional Arrays to create a tictactoe board? (not full game)

Tags: java

The goal of this assignment was for me to use a 2 Dimensional Array that prints a 3x3 tic tac board. While the instructions say it can have any arrangements on "x", "o", and blank spaces, it turns out it can't all be blank spaces (which my teacher had to specify after a cheeky attempt). Anyways, an example of a sample output would be like this:
[image]

Anyways, I decided that maybe I should randomize what fills up the grid (I was told that just doing it is easier and simpler but I can't figure out how to code that). Unfortunately, I'm stuck on how to fulfill the proper format and what fills up inside is mostly blanks and Os. Can someone perhaps suggest a better way to do this or help a bit? Thanks.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] tictactoe = new String[3][3];
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            int onetwo =(int)(3*Math.random())+1;
            if (onetwo == 1){
                tictactoe[i][j] = "x";
            }
            if (onetwo == 2){
                tictactoe[i][j] = "o";
            }
            else{
                tictactoe[i][j] = " ";
            }
            if ( i < 3)
                System.out.print(tictactoe[i][j] + " | ");
            }
        }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("---------");
   }
}
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: *"what fills up inside is mostly blanks and Os"* That's because you're missing an `else`, as in `} else if (onetwo == 2) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare a string like:

```
String alphabet = "nxo";
```

And in your randomise function:

```
String letter = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt()); // not sure about the syntax but that would be the logic for getting a random value
```

Just fill that in your array with your already existing for loops

Comment: N = null, x = x, o = 0; just to clarify